# Failed to upgrade PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.3 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, package-management, php

I've try to upgrade my php version on Centos 7, but I got this error:

[image]

also when I try to add `--skip-broken` it displayed the following message:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:

oniguruma5-6.9.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-safe
php-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-cli-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-common-7.3.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-common-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-gd-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-json-7.3.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-json-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-mbstring-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-mysqlnd-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-pdo-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64 from remi-php73
php-xml-7.3.13-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php73
php71w-gd-7.1.33-1.w7.x86_64 from webtatic
```

and I check again my PHP version , still 7.1. 
Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: The “remi” repo appears to be for el6.

Comment: Also you have both webtatic and remi-php73 repos enabled?!  Pick one.